# Link CName record to another domain, but without subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

Is it possible to link "mydomain.com" to "app.iriscouch.com" using a CNAME record?

My service provider app says a CNAME record must have a subdomain.

And A record must link to an IP.

Comment: If app.iriscouch.com has a unique IP (not shared) that you can create an A record pointing from mydomain.com to that IP. Otherwise, not possible using DNS.

Answer (score 5):

I do not believe this is possible, per - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655235/is-root-domain-cname-to-other-domain-allowed-by-dns-rfc

Either way it is inadvisable. Instead, consider just using a sub-domain for the CNAME and then force rewrite (something elegant and ubiquitous like mod_rewrite) attempts to reach the base domain to that subdomain, either based on a criteria or in all scenarios.

Also, consider the fact that most DNS interfaces would disallow such a thing even if it were 'technically' possible. I know that the DNS interface at the hosting company I work for would prevent this action.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I think they are correct, you'll most likely have to do a redirect from `mydomain.com`. As you mentioned a CNAME record cannot exist on the main domain.

Some hosted DNS solutions can do this for you as well, I've used https://web.easydns.com before.

Answer (score 0):

It would be incorrect to create a CNAME from your zone to a subzone. By definition a CNAME cannot have another record at the same apex as any other record (this is modified by DNSSEC to allow RRSIG, NSEC(3), etc). For example at the zone cut (into your zone example.com) if you would create a CNAME to app.example.com there is no zone delegation glue there for resolvers to state the authority of the nameserver to example.com. So you basically break yourself.

What I would suggest is since your not asking for a DNAME configuration that it's likely your just trying to configure your A record to app.example.com. So why not set the IP of app.example.com at example.com and CNAME app.example.com back to example.com?